# Connecting wordpress container t a multi database container

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I'm required to build a multi-database MySQL container, this was straight forward as I followed this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-mysql-databases-with-one-mysql-container

Now I have to run my wordpress container and connect it to one of these databases, I tried what I already know:

```
docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=pass --network wordpress --name wordpress --link mysqldb:mysql -p 4123:80 -v "$PWD/html":/var/www/html -d wordpress
```

where mysqldb is the container's name but with no luck whatsoever.

What is the proper syntax to link wordpress container with one of these databases? They are two, the other one should be used for another purpose.

I don't have the liberty to use two MySQL containers, any advice is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the name when you linked `mysqldb:mysql` is the database server hostname. In your sample, it is `mysql`

You can cat `/etc/hosts` to confirm the mysql hostname in your application container `wordpress`

Second, you don't have to build a seperate multi-database containers, you just link several times.

```
# create first mysql database container.
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql
4914c6fbb3e870b530fc5713908cd918ad3d1c43ebbeb460b878857328934f95

# create second mysql database container.
$ docker run --name some-mysql2 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql
72090be34a5d62ea53edd87e4b513ad5c0c413fe8b223fe36c2aae6938fd77c4

# run your application with links
$ docker run -d --name wordpress --link some-mysql:mysql1 --link some-mysql2:mysql2 wordpress
f1d6fbc2fcf30862efd0a4a4882425e359a2442c1476c0256c338e80a46ae66d
```

You can check the hostname in wordpress container

```
$ docker exec -ti f1 bash
root@f1d6fbc2fcf3:/var/www/html# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  mysql1 4914c6fbb3e8 some-mysql             # <= here is the first mysql hostname
172.17.0.3  mysql2 72090be34a5d some-mysql2            # <= here is the second mysql hostname
172.17.0.4  f1d6fbc2fcf3
root@f1d6fbc2fcf3:/var/www/html#
```